# Limitador de caracteres no text-box do ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor, html-helpers

Estou querendo implementar um limitador de caracteres pra essa text-box, mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso. É uma pagina de inserção de posts em um portal e o titulo precisa ter um limite.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Titulo)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Titulo, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Titulo)                                  
    </div> 
</div>
```

Como posso implementar um limitador?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Titulo, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Isso é ASP.NET, não tem nada a ver com ASP Classic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar desta forma:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Titulo, new { @maxlength="10", @class = "form-control" })
```